# Listing all subcateogries on page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new with wordpress. I have started learning wordpress from today. I went through all the basics of wordpress, found interesting.

Now as beginner I have doubt. I want to create a list of category on single page. Suppose,
I have a page named country. I have category named Countrylist. Now I wish to connnect category to page so that when page is opened all sub categories of Countrylist is shown on that page as a hyperlink.
Like

```
America
India
Russia
Pakistan.
```

Means list of all subcategories should be shown on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom menus to do that.

1. Click on Menus under Appearance
2. Then click on the + to create a new menu
3. Name that menu whatever you think is appropriate.
4. And you can add categories/pages to that menu from the left hand
   side.
5. Then you can add the "custom menu" sidebar widget to the Countrylist page that shows
   pages only from that menu

That should do the trick.